# Xcode attach to process could not locate installed application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8.3

When I use the iOS simulator I've no issues with attaching to a process. But when I want to attach to a process on my iPhone it doesn't work. When I type in the process name and click on Attach it takes a while before showing me the following error:

[image: Could not locate installed application error Xcode]

It seems that I get the same error for any process identifier, even when the process identifier doesn't exist:

[image: Here is me typing some random non-existing process name]

I think this issue is due to my iPhone (5S iOS 8.3), because on another iPhone (5) I don't have this issue. Can someone please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was only occurring on my iPhone 5S and after a factory reset the issue didn't occur anymore.